# InDesign: Accessing document dictionary

Tags: javascript, adobe-indesign, extendscript

In my script, I am copying a table of cells that have a lot of text in them. This text has a bunch of custom hyphenation rules that are saved in the document dictionary, NOT in the user dictionary. This is accessed in the UI by opening *User dictionary* and selecting the document under *Target*.

When copying the table to another document, these rules are unfortunately not copied with it, and the text is changed.

How can I access this custom document dictionary so that my hyphenations are retained in the target document?

It is possible to access the user dictionary with `UserDictionary`, but where is the document dictionary located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this myself since I finally found the proper class to use:

The document dictionary can be accessed using `HyphenationExceptions`. To get all custom hyphenations from my target document, I did the following:

```
var myHyphenations = app.activeDocument.hyphenationExceptions;
for (var i = 0; i < myHyphenations.length; i++) {
    if (myHyphenations[i].name === "Danish") {
        var mySourceDictionary = myHyphenations[i];
        mySourceHyphenations = mySourceDictionary.addedExceptions;
        break
        }
    }
```

For some reason, it seems that it is NOT possible to get a certain HyphenationException using its name.

In other words, the below code does not work (it actually gives me a Norwegian dictionary):

```
var mySourceDictionary = app.activeDocument.hyphenationExceptions.item("Danish");
```

For this reason, I had to loop the array until I found the one I needed: ("Danish").